# how to add missing value of dictionary to an array

Tags: python, dictionary

I have these :

```
df1=[('f', {'abe': 1}), ('f', {'abeli': 1}), ('f', {'mos': 1}), ('f', {'esc': 1})]

df2= [('l', {'mos': 1}), ('l', {'esc': 1})]
```

I want to generate two arrays

```
L1=[1,1,1,1]

L2=[0,0,1,1]
```

0 because 'abe' and 'abeli' are not present in the second arrays.

```
dict1_part = [sc[1] for sc in df1]

dict2_part = [sc[1] for sc in df2]

L1=len(dict1_part)

L2=len(dict2_part)

print(L1 , L2)

buckets=[]


for items in dict1_part:

  pl=items.keys()

  Value=items.values()

  print("pl",plant)

  print("dict2_part",dict2_part)


  if pl in dict2_part.keys():

    buckets.append(1)

  else:

    buckets.append(0)


print(buckets)
```

Comment: Is the list of expected keys specified independently, or is it whatever is found in `df1`?

Comment: yes whatever found in df1 and vise versa

Comment: What is the actual *question*? How does the result of the code differ from what you expect, and what is your understanding of why that happens? What exactly is the part you need help making work?

Comment: I don't know how to get the array with 0

Answer (score 0):

First, find the keys for each dictionary in `df1` and then use `dict.get`:

```
df1=[('f', {'abe': 1}), ('f', {'abeli': 1}), ('f', {'mos': 1}), ('f', {'esc': 1})]
df2= [('l', {'mos': 1}), ('l', {'esc': 1})]
df_keys= [list(b.keys())[0] for _, b in df1]
first_array = [b.get(c) for (_, b), c in zip(df1, df_keys)]
second_array = [0 if not any(x in c for _, c in df2) else [b[x] for _, b in df2 if x in b][0] for x in df_keys]
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I sort df1 and df2 before fnding the keys?